# Prerender.io: everything is cached, but facebook can't get correct info for front-page

Tags: angularjs, share, prerender

I have a weird anomaly. While my content pages work fine with facebook sharing (http://example.com/31) , my first page however (http://example.com/), for some reason, gets invalid data when doing fetch in facebook debug tool (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/).

When checking prerender, everything seems to be cached correctly.

Where might the problem reside? I'm thinking htacces, but not sure.

Comment: Send me an email at todd@prerender.io. There isn't enough information here to diagnose what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a couple of things: 1) you need to explicitly send the Facebook crawler to prerender.io 2) you will need to include the FB Graph tags in your page.

Comment: I think I have a problem with the first point you make. But I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. In angular routeprovider I have: .when('/', {
   controller: 'home',
   templateUrl: 'views/home.html'
  }). Could this be the problem, as facebook goes straight for index file and does not check the prerendered version or smth...

Answer (score 0):

I think i solved it. I had this in htaccess file in root folder:

```
# Don't rewrite files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

And I had to move this after the prerender.io code in htaccess file.